# Firebase deployment works locally but not on GitHub Action

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, github-actions, firebase-cli

I'm trying to build a CI/CD pipeline for my project that uses Firebase Cloud Functions.

The functions code is written in TypeScript.

Deploying the code from my local MacBook works perfectly. However, when deploying the same exact code from the GitHub Action runner it fails with an error:

```
/home/runner/work/geonotes-backend/geonotes-backend/functions/lib/handlers/createNoteActionHandler.js:11
    return sendOutput({ note_id: note?.id });
                                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1052:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1100:27)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1394:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:984:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1024:19)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1338:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/geonotes-backend/geonotes-backend/functions/lib/index.js:28:51)
```

This looks like Firebase is not accepting the optional chaining syntax, but it should since the function runs on Node.js 14.
Furthermore, the same syntax is accepted perfectly by the CLI running on my machine.

I have verified that both my machine and the GitHub runner are using the same versions:

- Node.js v14.17.4
- NPM v6.14.14
- Firebase CLI v9.16.0
- TypeScript v4.3.5

I have also tried to run my action on `macos-latest` instead of `ubuntu-latest` with no luck.

This is one of the runs that is failing, with --debug enabled:

https://github.com/emilioschepis/geonotes-backend/runs/3261106553

Does anyone have an idea about what could be wrong?

Comment: Hi Emilio, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue in a build using Github Actions (using Node 14.X as well)

Comment: Hi, unfortunately haven't had any luck yet. This is the issue I have opened on Firebase's repository, if you want to bump it up: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3676